# React-native failed propType on Image component

Tags: javascript, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am just starting out with React-native and have a pretty decent grasp on React for creating web apps... I am running into a confusing issue here that never occured when working with react for the web.

Basically I am rendering a component whose image is being dynamically generated by mapping over an array of objects in its parent component.

```
export default class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Image source={this.props.source}/>
    );
  }
};
```

And its parent component:

```
export default class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   this.state = {
      images:[
        { src: './src/images/1.png'},
        { src: '/src/images/2.png'},
        { src: './src/images/3.png'}
      ]
    }
   }

  render() {
    let images = this.state.images.map((image) => {
      return(<ImageComponent source={image.src}  />);
    })

    return (
      <View>
        {images}
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

**In device simulator I am getting the following error:**

"Warning: Failed propType:Invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'Image' check the render method of 'BasicComponent'"

Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You should either require the local assets or use object with `uri` key.

So either in `MainComponent`:

```
this.state = {
  images:[
    require('./src/images/1.png'),
    require('./src/images/2.png'),
    require('./src/images/3.png')
  ]
}
```

or in `BasicComponent`:

```
return (
  <Image 
    source={{uri: this.props.source}}
  />
);
```

Comment: Requiring the local assets was the way to go thank you for your help @zvona

Comment: uri property in source props work for me. require method did not. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Cheers! thank you! By the way, shouldn’t that be in the documentation? If you see the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#source) now you would have to guess that if you didn’t find this answer…

Comment: Thanks @zvona, but how can you know if the props is an image object or a string?

Comment: but in my case i have some other data with the image... how am i gonna manage that? 

const DATA = [
    { id: 1, url: require('../../assets/country/bangladesh_one.png'), value: 'bangladesh' },
    { id: 2, url: require('../../assets/country/india.png'), value: 'india' },
    { id: 3, url: require('../../assets/country/malaysia.png'), value: 'malaysia' },
    { id: 4, url: require('../../assets/country/monaco.png'), value: 'monaco' },
]

Answer (score 12):

you should be use uri for set source image

```js
return (
  <Image 
    source={{uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/docs/assets/p_cat2.png'}}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image source= {{uri: "https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1024/1*QY5S4senfFh-mIViSi5A_Q.png"}} style = {{width:100,height:100}}/>
```

add **uri** name in source, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image source={require('./pathToImage/image.png')}/>
```

This also works if your using something in your project files rather than a URL.