# Load Image in React native from props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a list of images from a base component by sending down title and image URL.

Everything works fine if I'm rendering the images like this:

```
 <Image source={require('../assets/images/myImage.png')} />
```

The issue is coming when I'm trying to render the image from props:

```
class ListItem extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.title}<Text>
          <Image source={require(this.props.imageUri)} />
        </View>
      );
    }
};

ListItem.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  imageUri: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

As a result, I'm getting the next error:

> calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this
>   was found: `require(this.props.imageUri)`.

I've also tried to render the images using `uri`

```
<Image source={{uri: this.props.imageUri}} />
```

package.js

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Comment: Did you try `source={this.props.imageUri}`? What is an eample value of `this.props.imageUri`? Are you trying to use a relative path or an absolute one?

Comment: And check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460827/react-native-failed-proptype-on-image-component to see if it helps.

Comment: `source={this.props.imageUri}` - Yes, I did try it. I'm not getting any error but the image is not rendered. `this.props.imageUri = ../assets/images/myImage.png`

Comment: `And check stackoverflow.com/questions/36460827/… to see if it helps` - it doesn't help as I don't want to store my image into the `state`. There are about 100 possible combinations of images which may change in the future. I'm looking to send down the path from a Json/APi

Comment: You can't write a dynamic require statement like that, it says it in the error, it wants a string literal

Comment: @DominicTobias thanks for the feedback. Any idea about how can I render this images dynamically?

Comment: Is it a list of known paths, or totally dynamic? @rm-rf.

Comment: It is a list of known paths

Comment: <Image source={{uri: this.props.imageUri}} />
That should have worked and is how you're supposed to do it, You shouldn't have to require them if it is an external uri....
I would absolutely make sure they are valid strings with console.logs. Also they can't be http must be https on ios

Answer (score 6):

If you're using remote images with `uri` they can be dynamic but `require` for local images needs to resolve the paths at build time so they can't be. Create a hash of known paths:

```
const imageNames = {
   apple: require('./images/apple.png'),
   orange: require('./images/orange.png'),
};
```

And refer to them by their name:

```
class ListItem extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.title}<Text>
          <Image source={imageNames[this.props.imageName]} />
        </View>
      );
    }
};

ListItem.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  imageName: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(imageNames)),
};

// e.g.
<ListItem imageName="orange" />
```