# Jest: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type [number]

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest with react-native to run unit test cases. And whenever it encounters `Image` it throws the following warning

```
 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type [number].
          at Component (~/.../node_modules/react-native/jest/mockComponent.js:28:18)
          at SummaryTile (~/.../src/components/home/SomeComponent.tsx:18:3)

      23 |   >
      24 |     {backgroundImg || (
    > 25 |       <Image
         |       ^
      26 |         source={require('images/cloud.png')}
      27 |       />
```

I tried to replace the code to

```
<Image src={{uri: require('images/cloud.png')}} />
```

as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36460928/3855179 but it started throwing the following warning and the application breaks

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type [string, number].
    at Image (http://expo_url:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:76209:43)
```

```
Jest Version: 26.6.3
React Native version: 0.64.3
Node Version: 16.14.2
```

Any idea how this can be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your file structure along with the jest configuration file.

But my best guess is - jest isn't able to find the file in the designated location.

Few things that can be tried:

(1) try changing file location to be a bit more explicit like so:

eg - if image in same directory -- `source={require('./images/cloud.png')}`

eg - if one directory up -- `source={require('../images/cloud.png')}`

---

(2) try mocking out the image in test file like so:

```
jest.mock("images/cloud.png")
```

---

(3) Specify a location in jest configuration file (or in package.json file if you have a jest key there) for all image types, this way jest will use that as the image source whenever it encounters an image:

eg -

```js
 moduleNameMapper: {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$": "<rootDir>/images/dummy-image.js",
    }
```

More doco on moduleNameWrapper here - https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring

Comment: Hi, @nishkaush thanks for pointing to the `moduleNameWrapper`. I am currently using tsconfig and in that, I have added an alias for the path of the images. I fixed the issue by adding the following to the `moduleNameWrapper`. `'^images/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/images/$1'`

Comment: @SumitSurana, thanks for your comment. Using the alias and `moduleNameWrapper` was the solution for me as well. Example for others: `require('@assets/images/splash-logo.png')` solved with `'^@assets/images/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/assets/images/$1',`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to use an image, that has an space in its name, like `<rootDir>/stupidly_named images.png`. It's seems, React Native is happy with these naming, but not Jest. Filling in the space (`<rootDir>/stupidly_named_images.png`) fixed the error. And I am not using any `moduleNameWrapper`:

```
"react-native": "0.68.2"
"jest": "^28.1.0"
"@testing-library/react-native": "^9.1.0"
```