# jest error: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`

Tags: react-native, jestjs, eslint

Getting this error with running jest test. Have tried a lot to disable prop types rule:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type [number].
        in Image (at Welcome.js:134)
        in Welcome (created by Connect(Welcome))
        in Connect(Welcome) (at Welcome.test.js:25)
        in Provider (at Welcome.test.js:24)

      132 |             {!global.isFirstTime &&
      133 |                 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.backIcon} onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>
    > 134 |                     <Image source={Images.back} />
          |                    ^
      135 |                 </TouchableOpacity>
      136 |             }
      137 |
```

Already added the rule in `.eslintrc.json`

```
"rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0
}
```

Also adding jest config moduleNameMapper

```
moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '^(.+)\\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp4|mkv|avi|webm|swf|wav|mid)$': 'jest-static-stubs/$2'
    },
```

So when the test runs Images.back contains:
`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

1. "react": "16.13.1",
2. "react-native": "0.63.5 ",
3. "eslint": "^8.39.0",
4. "jest": "26.6.3",

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest: Failed prop type: Invalid prop \`source\` supplied to \`Image\`, expected one of type \[number\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71761668/jest-failed-prop-type-invalid-prop-source-supplied-to-image-expected-one)

Comment: That answer did not help me. As I have verified the file is found and mapped as data: uri by the jest test.

Comment: as I see Images.back is base64file and not a link, so I think you are passing the source image to the Image react-native as a file without adding a uri or link, try to added it like this:

    `<Image source={{uri: Images.back}} />`

Comment: yes you are right. this is not my code, but it works perfectly in the mobile. it even passes the test, but jest keep coming with this warning. Maybe to solve this is to just disable this validation. `back: require('../assets/images/back.png'),`

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<Image source={{uri: Images.back}} style={{height:50, width:50}} />
```

Comment: Have done that already. This works in the test and solves my problem. But does not show any images in the runtime. So not my solution.

Comment: Please check onError on Image component. or make force update after get image source.