# jest with Image giving source prop types error

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs

Getting this prop types error only in jest test run:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type [number]


//Images declaration:
const Images = {
...
back: require('../assets/images/back.png'),
...

//Component snip which is  giving prop types error

<Image source={Images.back} />
```

The problem in jest fixes and test passes when using

```
<Image source={{uri: Images.back}} />
```

But since this is a static file, crashes in the app.
Im using a module mapper for static file in jest.config.js

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^(.+)\\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp4|mkv|avi|webm|swf|wav|mid)$': 'jest-static-stubs/$2'
},
```

so Image.back is giving out `data:uri`.

Please help on how to correctly configure jest or to resolve the prop types error?
Thanks you.

```
"react": "16.13.1"
"react-native": "0.63.5 "
"jest": "26.6.3",
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460827/react-native-failed-proptype-on-image-component answer your question?